# svg filter not working in mozilla firefox after zoom

Tags: jquery, css, d3.js, svg

I have a dynamic d3.js tree and I am applying glow filter to elements on click. When I zoom the tree and click on any node, elements are getting hidden instead of highlighting. This is happening only in Firefox. In chrome it is working fine.

```
<filter id="yellow-glow" x="-5000" y="-5000" width="10000" height="10000" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
  <feFlood result="flood" flood-color="yellow" flodd-opacity="1"/>  
  <feComposite in="flood" result="mask" in2="SourceGraphic" operator="in"/>
  <feMorphology in="mask" result="dilated" operator="dilate" radius="2"/>
  <feGaussianBlur in="dilated" result="blurred" stdDeviation="5"/>
  <feMerge><feMergeNode in="blurred"/>
  <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/></feMerge>
```

Here is the [working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nq6bb581/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine when you reduce the filter's dimensions

```
<filter id="yellow-glow" x="-500" y="-500" width="1000" height="1000"
```

I guess something is overflowing in Firefox's SVG renderer. You may want to file a bug to Mozilla.

Comment: Ideally what should be the x,y,width and height values for filter element. My d3 tree is draggable and zoomable